# max defers and failures per hour (5/5 (100%)) allowed - No CPanel

Tags: php, config, cpanel, phpmailer

I am sending a lot of emails per hour using PHPMailer on our intranet.

Most of the emails the application is sending are being bouced back with:

```
Domain *** has exceeded the max defers and failures per hour (5/5 (100%)) allowed. Message discarded.
```

I have seen that there are fixes for this using CPanel but I don't have CPanel installed on this server.

Does anyone know of another way around it?

Comment: are you sending mail through some smtp server ?

Comment: Sending using SMTP, yes

Comment: I doubt it. I'd guess you're using the server's sendmail

Comment: As I stated in the question, I am using PHPMailer to send with `$mail->IsSMTP();` and `$mail->SMTPAuth = true;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPMailer has no features to mitigate this, so it's up to either the calling code or underlying infrastructure to do it. There are several strategies you could follow:

- Generate your message requests into a queue, then have a separate
  process that sends them at a rate that will pass your upstream mail
  server's restrictions. I suspect this is what cpanel will be doing.
- Get the upstream mail server limits lifted - if this is an intranet,
  there is no real reason to limit these sends.
- It may be that it's not your sending but your upstream mail server
  that is having the problem. In that case the mail server needs tuning
  to do at least per-domain throttling. Postfix has support for this
  out of the box, but you will need to configure it.